# Macro Optimization ifs seem to slow it down a lat

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I would love to optimize this code so that it executes faster...

```
Sub gotocfstatement()

    If ActiveCell.Row < 10 Then Exit Sub

    If ActiveCell.Row > 5001 Then Exit Sub

    If Sheet1.Range("p" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "" Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    Filename = Sheet1.Range("p" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value

    Sheet2.Range("b9").Value = Filename

    If Sheet2.Range("b15").Value = "" Then
    Sheet2.Range("b14").Value = Sheet2.Range("s1").Value

    Else

    Sheet2.Range("b14").Value = Sheet2.Range("b15").Value

    End If

    If Sheet2.Range("a81").Value = "" Then
    Sheet2.Range("a85").Value = Sheet2.Range("ab1").Value

    Else

    Sheet2.Range("a85").Value = Sheet2.Range("a81").Value

    End If

    Sheets("cash flow statement").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps better on Code Review.

Comment: What's the overall point of this macro? Also, at the very least that first line can be `If Activecell.Row < 10 or Activecell.Row > 5001 Then Exit Sub`...

Comment: There are no loops here so it seems like this should complete pretty quickly.  What's the exact problem?